# Does the universe loses its physicality during the sleep of Brahma?

Tags: brahma, time, universe

Brahma has two states: waking state and sleep state. I want to know the status of the physical universe during the sleep state of Brahma. Observe the bolded lines. I want to know the actual Sanskrit lines for them and their literal meaning.

> The learned say that these twelve thousand years (of the deities)
> constitute what is called a yuga. A thousand such yugas compose a
> single day of Brahman. The same is the duration of Brahman's night.
> **With the commencement of Brahman's day the universe begins to start
> into life. During the period of universal dissolution the Creator
> sleeps, having recourse to yoga-meditation. When the period of slumber
> expires, He awakes**. That then which is Brahman's day extends for a
> thousand such yugas. His nights also extends for a thousand similar
> yugas. They who know this are said to know the day and the night. On
> the expiry of His night, Brahman, waking up, modifies the
> indestructible chit by causing it to be overlaid with Avidya. He then
> causes Consciousness to spring up, whence proceeds Mind which is
> identical with the Manifest.
>
> [[Section 231, Mokshadharma Parva, Santi Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m12/m12b058.htm)

This paragraph is saying that

during the waking up state of Brahma, the universe begins to start into life. During the sleep state, the universe dissolves.

I want to know the exact meaning or detailed description of **begins to start into life** and **dissolution** along with Sanskrit citations. Does losing physicality a part of dissolution and gaining physicality a part of beginning to start into life?

Comment: In the Sanskrit version, it's the same chapter 231 in Mokṣadharma parva, Śānti Parva. Verse you can find in the version you have because it varies in the same chapter in different versions

Comment: In *night*, there is no life, the universe is without any names and forms. No objects, no substance, no beings.

Comment: @Bingming So, you mean the universe loses its physicality?

Comment: If you mean a physical form as such, it's not there.

Comment: When Earth merges into water into fire into air into akasha into subtle forms into avyakta, that is dissolution. PraLaya - absorption into the supreme. Avyakta means non physical. So there is no physicality.

Comment: when brahma sleeps only first 3 worlds (out of 7) are gone. when he wakes up, he creates the sun, moon etc. as in previous kalpa (yatha purvam akalpayat). when brahma's lifetime is over, then all 7 (or 14) worlds are destroyed in mahapralaya. of course there are multiple brahmandas too, so idk if all brahmas take birth/death in sync or not.